# How do I represent this geometric series in R?

Tags: r, probability

I am reading a paper on creating a market maker, and am trying to implement some of the ideas. How can I represent this series in R? I know the first equation should output a probability, while the second should output a number near the bid price.

[image: A priori for a sell order]

[image: To calculate the bid price]

I have just used multiple seq() functions to try and solve this, although the error may come from my distribution formulas.

```r
Psell <- seq(from = v0 - 4*sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T), to = ba$Bid.Price[1] - 1, 
    by = (I + (1 - I)*.2)*dnorm(72.62, v0, sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T))) + 
  seq(from = ba$Bid.Price[1], to = v0 + 4*sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T) - 1,
      by = (I + (1 - I)*.2)*dnorm(72.62, v0, sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T)))

Psell <- tail(Psell, 1)

Pb <- (1/Psell) * (seq(from = v0 - 4*sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T), to = ba$Bid.Price[1] - 1, 
                       by = (I + (1 - I)*.2)*72.62*dnorm(72.62, v0, sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T))) + 
                     seq(from = ba$Bid.Price[1], to = v0 + 4*sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T) - 1,
                         by = (I + (1 - I)*.2)*72.62*dnorm(72.62, v0, sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T))))
Pb
```

Psell returns 144.2665, 
Pb returns 0.9908123

Expecting a probability for Psell, and a number closer to 72 for Pb

Please let me know if I need to explain variables that I used or anything else!

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think `seq` does what you think it does. Have you read its documentation? For a solution I think you should use vectorized computations and then `sum`.

Comment: Oh thank you, I will update that accordingly and see what I come up with

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Used sequence to generate the range of numbers I need for the series, and then used a for loop to apply my operation to each element.

```r
lst <- seq(from = v0 - 4*sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T), to = v0 + 4*sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T), by = 1)

count <- 0
for(i in 1:length(lst)){
  temp <- (I + (1 - I)*.2)*dnorm(lst[i], v0, sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T))
  count <- count + temp
}
count

count2 <- 0
for(i in 1:length(lst)){
  temp2 <- (I + (1 - I)*.2)*lst[i]*dnorm(lst[i], v0, sd(ba$Price, na.rm = T))
  count2 <- temp2 + count2
}

count2 * 1/count
```

Comment: Nice! A recommendation: You don't even need the loop, just use `lst` directly in your computations. They will automatically be applied on every element. Afterwards you can use `sum` to add up all the elements.

Comment: Wow thank you! I guess I like to overcomplicate things! R really makes some things very easy